# SOQL query Contact name not queryable

Tags: apex, soql

what is the issue from my SOQL query-

Select id, name,Status,type,LastModifiedDate,CreatedDate,Campaign.name,Campaign.Id,Campaign.Contact__r.id,Campaign.Contact__r.Name from CampaignMember where type='Contact'

I want the list for campaign member ,campaignid or contactname as well but above SOQL query doest return the contactname

[image]

Comment: And what is the error you are getting? Did you try querying the `Contact__c` field to fetch the ids? Did you try adding a clause like `Contact__c != NULL` to your query? Did you try using a different tool to export your data?

Comment: No error  getting, No did not try to different tool, tell me tool name to fetch record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Contact is on the CampaignMember record, so you should be able to:

```
SELECT 
  Name, Status, Type, LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate,
  Campaign.Name, CampaignId, ContactId, Contact.Name
FROM CampaignMember
WHERE Type = 'Contact'
```